# Python - can you add a tooltip on a wx.CheckBox object?

Tags: python-3.x, wxwidgets

And if so, how would one add a tooltip to a checkbox object? It appears that the control inherits from wxWindow which has tooltips, so can it be added to a wxCheckBox?

Thanks!

Comment: what version of python? wxPython? What OS? What toolkit? Did you compile everything yourself or download from the official repository?

Comment: Python 3.6, Mac OS High Sierra, using Eclipse and I downloaded directly from Python org. I'm starting to think that my Mac OS might have something to do with it - can't recall if Mac even uses ToolTips. If the OS is the reason, can I update the status bar when mousing over the control? 

Thanks!

Comment: what version of wxPython do you use? can you try to download the original wx C++ library compile it and try the same thing in the widgets sample there? Just follow instructions in http://www.wxwidgets.org/develop/code-repository/, then do `cd wxWidgets && mkdir buildCocoa && cd buildCocoa && ../configure --with-osx-cocoa && make && cd samples/widgets && make && open widgets.app`. Switch to the combo box page on the left and see if any menu have a possibility to set tooltip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is what I did to solve the issue. I needed to bind the mouse over event to the tooltip.

```
self.ignCB = wx.CheckBox(self, 0, label='Ignore Errors')
self.ignCB.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.on_mouse_over)
def on_mouse_over(self, event):
            self.ignCB.SetToolTipString('Continue on Download Errors,    Skips Unavailable Videos within a Playlist')
```

I first create the CheckBox with the label Ignore Errors. Then, I needed to bind the mouse over event to the control, and call the mouse over handler which shows the tool tip.

Hopefully this will help someone else out as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

self.YourCheckboxObject.SetToolTip(wx.ToolTip("Paste your tooltip text here"))

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything. Here is what I did.
`code`       _twoSBSizer.Add(wx.CheckBox(self, label='Select Options'))
        self.ignCB = wx.CheckBox(self, 0, label='Ignore Errors')
        self.ignCB.SetToolTip(wx.ToolTip("Continue on Download Errors, Skips Unavailable Videos within a Playlist"))  `code`

Can't seem to get the code tag to work....